# MYSQL Order first results by less than 1 hour then display the rest desc

Tags: php, mysql

I've been scratching my head of the best way to do this, I run a small forum and want to change the ordering of the posts.

```
ID | Subject | lastpost
____________________
1  | Test    | 2014-06-2012 00:00:00
2  | Test    | 2014-06-2012 00:00:00 
3  | Test    | 2014-06-2012 00:00:00
4  | Test    | 2014-06-2012 00:00:00
5  | Test    | 2014-06-2012 00:00:00
6  | Test    | 2014-06-2012 00:00:00
7  | Test    | 2014-06-2012 00:00:00
```

Ideally I would like it to display results where lastpost < 60 mins **THEN** display the rest by the id desc

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER by `lastpost` > (time), `id` desc
```

but seem to be drawing a blank.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY (`lastpost` > date_sub(now(), interval 60 minute)) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN `lastpost` > date_sub(now(), interval 60 minute) THEN lastpost ELSE NULL END) DESC,
         id;
```

The first condition puts the most recent posts first.  The second sorts those by the post date (presumably the most recent first).  The rest are sorted by `id` desc.

Comment: That sorts the table by the lastpost, but I want it so that it still displays the whole table and not just one hour posts. So sort first 1 hour posts in order of last updated then the rest of the table descending by id.

Comment: I don't have enough points to downvote. I've just tested but it returns a syntax error.

Comment: The `where` should have been an `order by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Downvoters rarely give a reason why. I've given a +1

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . At about the same time, two of my answers had downvotes as well as other correct answers on the questions.  Unfortunately, that sometimes happens.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If it happened at the same time, then I'd say it may have very well came from the same *drive-by* downvoter. You're a respected member here and with a high degree of knowledge in this field, which I for one have learned a lot from. It's unfortunate that someone doesn't do the "very least" and explain the downvote. But as you say, it sometimes happens. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

I assume that lastpost is of column type `datetime` and not a string - if not, you should change that.
So

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastpost > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ORDER BY id DESC
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I asked, I asked how to display the the first of the table sorted by the posts within one hour then the rest of the table sorted by id desc.